# Linux Mininet Scapy error

Tags: linux, scapy, mininet

I am trying to launch scapy using Mininet and get this error:

```
IOError : [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Error happens in

```
linux.py,line 151, in read_routes
ifreq = ioctl(s, SIOCGIFADDR,struct.pack("16s16x",LOOPBACK_NAME))
```

Any solutions or ideas?

note: host was added into existed network,may be this cause some misconfiguration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No loopback interface was added. Solution (from terminal):

```
ifconfig lo up
ifconfig lo 127.0.0.1
```